# A Pairing Puzzle for Christmas

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Show how the following words and phrases may be sorted into pairs.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REITERATING | DRILLING | MR GUM | LONG |
| ANGLICANS | MAN SINS | ULSTER | GRIPES |
| READ PAPER | ENGAGE | POLLS | VOTED |
| PIPPIN | MIND-MURDERS | DISLIKING | DIED |
| SCAB | DRAINAGE | MAMA | EASILY |
|  | WIGWAMS | GRIDS |  |

Can you find another pair which fits into this group?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another pair which might fit here is:

> **HENCH** and **FERNS**

Because:

> These words can be paired up to form anagrams of **gifts in the song, [*The Twelve Days of Christmas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song))**!

Like so:

> (12) MR GUM + MIND-MURDERS = **DRUMMERS DRUMMING**
>  (11) PIPPIN + GRIPES = **PIPERS PIPING**
>  (10) DRAINAGE + POLLS = **LORDS A-LEAPING**
>  (9) ANGLICANS + DIED = **LADIES DANCING**
>  (8) DISLIKING + MAMA = **MAIDS A-MILKING**
>  (7) MAN SINS + WIGWAMS = **SWANS A-SWIMMING**
>  (6) ENGAGE + EASILY = **GEESE A-LAYING**
>  (5) LONG + GRIDS = **GOLD RINGS**
>  (4) DRILLING + SCABS = **CALLING BIRDS**
>  (3) ...
>  (2) ULSTER + VOTED = **TURTLE DOVES**
>  (and a) REITERATING + READ PAPER = **PARTRIDGE IN A PEAR TREE**

My additional pair is similar and fills the gap left above:

> (3) HENCH + FERNS = **FRENCH HENS**!

---

<sub>PS Regarding the title, 'A Pairing Puzzle for Christmas':</sub>

> <sub>While the 'Christmas' connection to the song at the heart of this puzzle is evident ('*The Twelve Days of **Christmas***'), it's very pleasing that the '*pairing*' nature of the puzzle is also relevant to it, since the song's lyrics focus on the gifts given within a *couple*, i.e. a *pair* of lovers ('*My true love sent to me...*'). This makes the puzzle's word-pairing premise a really appropriate fit for the context!</sub>

Comment: Excellent and congratulations on reaching 40K in a year, a remarkable feat!

Comment: @hexomino Well, thank you very much :) I've had a lot of fun here... Unfortunately next year I really need to turn a considerable amount of attention back to another personal project so I shan't be here *quite* so often... but I'm sure that resolve will quickly fade and I'll be camped out here again for much of it ;-)